# Сравнить две картинки на разных сайтах

Tags: c#

Как сравнить две картинки на разных сайтах? Интересует именно само сравнение. Вся процедура по вытаскиванию картинок и обращение к сайтам не нужно.

Comment: Что значит сравнить?

Comment: ну сравнить это значить взять картинку a и сравнить ее с картиной b. Если они разные выдать сообщение.

Comment: Картинка это файл? Вы можете считать файлы в массивы байт и сравнить их?

Comment: Тут был подобный вопрос, в котором автор тоже долго не понимал, почему мы с VladD долго вытягиваем определение "одинаковости" картинок... У него было две картинки, которые выглядели как одинаковые чёрные квадраты, но на второй какие-то мелкие точечки были, которые видны только при увеличении. То, что зрительно они одинаковые - ещё не значит, что это будет просто объяснить компьютеру: пару точек поменял - якобы совсем другая картинка. И вместо тупого "размер изображений совпадает, поточечно совпали" можно заковыряться в очень сложные алгоритмы. Автору: так чего хотим-то? Вопрос слишком общий.

Comment: Можно сравнивать по каждому пикселю, можно с учетом инвариантности к аффинным преобразованиям, можно по особым точкам - Вы как желаете.

Comment: ну я прекрасно понимаю что сравнивать надо именно байты видимо как-то.. слышал что уже есть когнитивный сервис который это делает чуть ли не на 100%

Comment: Для сравнения 2 файлов побайтно не надо никаких сервисов. Просто читаете файл и сравниваете.

Comment: @Den Давайте вы отредактируете вопрос и точно скажете, что именно нужно. Точное сравнение байт? Попиксельное сравнение?

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Drawing;
```

Если речь про по пиксельное сравнение, Bm1 Bm2 это ваши картинки.

```
Bitmap filter1 = new Bitmap(Bm1);
Bitmap filter2 = new Bitmap(Bm2);  

if (filter1.Width != filter2.Width || filter2.Height != filter2.Height)
    return false;

for (int x = 0; x < filter1.Width; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < filter1.Height; y++)
       if(filter1.GetPixel(x, y) != filter2.GetPixel(x, y))
           return false;

return true;
```

Comment: Что такое Bm1 и Bm2 и чем это лучше побайтового сравнения? Спрашиваю, так как подозреваю, что создание битмапов и сравнение попиксельно скорее всего гораздо медленней, чем просто считать байты.

Comment: Верно, но работать будет медленно. Лучше делать через `Scan0`.

Comment: @tym32167, 1. Это пути к файлам. 2. Лучше тем, что во-первых, одинаковые попиксельно картинки могут иметь разные метаданные либо разные форматы. 3. А ещё этот метод можно немного изменить, чтобы сравнивать с определённой точностью и, например, получать, что картинки, сжатые в разном качестве, будут считаться одинаковыми.

Comment: @SkiF, я добавил. Только Bitmap'ы надо бы в using оборачивать.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72861/discussion-on-answer-by-skif------).

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос слишком широкий. Но допустим, ваша задача - проверять, скачивали вы уже эту картинку или нет.

В этом случае самый правильный подход - считать контрольную сумму файла и проверять, совпало или нет.

Видели наверное сайт virus total? Там такой же подход: каждый файл имеет уникальный "слепок" и можно быстро определить, про какой файл речь: тот же или другой.

Алгоритм используйте `SHA-256`, а не `MD5`: md5 хотя и быстрее, но больше шанс столкнуться с коллизией.

```
    public static string GetHash(byte[] data)
    {
        var stringBuilderb = new StringBuilder();

        using (var hash = SHA256.Create())
        {
            var result = hash.ComputeHash(data);

            foreach (var b in result)
                stringBuilderb.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
        }

        return stringBuilderb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72860/discussion-on-answer-by-a-k------).

Comment: @Qwertiy что мешает сравнить метаданные картинок, если их хеши совпали?

Comment: @Qwertiy шах и мат мне, у меня нет доступа к чату :)

Comment: @tym32167, должен быть: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7Zj5.png

Comment: @Qwertiy корпоративный фаервол не пустит

Comment: @tym32167, ладно, давай тут, потом ещё раз перенесу...

Comment: @tym32167, если метаданные разные, то хэши не совпадут. Если требуется проверять именно одинаковость картинок, то это false negative, а не false positive, соответственно при совпадении ничего проверять не надо, надо проверять при различии - а это уже фигня.

Comment: @Qwertiy "Коллизии всегда возможны" (С)

Comment: @Qwertiy ну то есть по сути остается вопрос автору - считает ли он картинки с одинаковым содержимым но разными метаданными разными? Вообще хочет ли он учитывать метаданные? - пока не понятно, что автору надо, наверное нет смысла дальше обсуждать, а то решим проблему, которой ни у кого нет :)

Comment: @tym32167, решим интересную проблему, с которой потом придут из гула по этому вопросу. Если речь о сравнении картинок, то обычно имеется в виду именно сравнение картинок. А алгоритмы сравнения файлов применимы к любым файлам и нет причин отдельно оговаривать, что будут сравниваться именно картинки.